# How to Animate Some Text to a Random Place in a Circular Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope So All Of You are Fine.

I have an assignment in which i have to animate some image to a circular div container at its any random place.

Right Now, I had done this Already.

jsfiddle.net/f4p6b/137

But The Problem is that the Container in jsfiddle is not Circular.

I want a Circular div container and image should drag/animate automatically on page load at some random place every time.

Kindly help me with the help of above jsfiddle code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css property to make your container circular

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: But Problem is that , The Image also animate to outside the circular div.

Answer (score 0):

As mentined above, you can add the `border-radious:50%` attirubute to make your Div circular.

Check out this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/internetbird/f4p6b/139/

Check out this updated fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/internetbird/f4p6b/141/

I added a function which produces a random point inside the circle (with a little math, which you can find more explination here: [Simplest way to plot points randomly inside a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642399/simplest-way-to-plot-points-randomly-inside-a-circle) )

Comment: But Problem is that , The Image also animate to outside the circular div.

Comment: You want to make all of the 4 values (min/maxX , min/maxY) inside the container circle?